# Magento 2 : Get payment additional data from frontend to backend always empty

Tags: magento2, php, payment-methods, payment

Im creating a custom payment method on an Magento 2 website using SecurePay API.
SecurePay Iframe Tokenise credit card and I will need that token to process the payment.
So I follow many tutorials to add additional_data to payment but I never could get any data even with the Magento doc tutorial: [devDocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/payments-integrations/base-integration/get-payment-info.html)

Here is my code :

securepay-method.js (in js/view/payment/method-renderer)

```
/**
     * Get data
     * @returns {Object}
     */
    getData: function () {
        var data = {
            'method': this.item.method,
            'additional_data': {
                'token': 'test'
            }
        };

        return data;
    },
```

DataAssignObserver.php (Observer)

```
<?php

namespace Appscore\SecurePay\Observer;


class DataAssignObserver extends AbstractDataAssignObserver
{
const TOKEN = 'token';

/**
 * @var array
 */
protected $additionalInformationList = [
    self::TOKEN,
];

/**
 * @param Observer $observer
 * @return void
 */
public function execute(Observer $observer)
{
    $data = $this->readDataArgument($observer);

    $additionalData = $data->getData(PaymentInterface::KEY_ADDITIONAL_DATA);
    if (!is_array($additionalData)) {
        return;
    }

    $paymentInfo = $this->readPaymentModelArgument($observer);

    foreach ($this->additionalInformationList as $additionalInformationKey) {
        if (isset($additionalData[$additionalInformationKey])) {
            $paymentInfo->setAdditionalInformation(
                $additionalInformationKey,
                $additionalData[$additionalInformationKey]
            );
        }
    }
}
```

}

events.xml (etc)

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="payment_method_assign_data_securepay">
    <observer name="securepay_gateway_data_assign" instance="Appscore\SecurePay\Observer\DataAssignObserver" />
</event>
```

SecurePay (Model)

```
/**
 * Capture Payment.
 *
 * @param \Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface $payment
 * @param float $amount
 * @return $this
 */
public function capture(\Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface $payment, $amount)
{

    $info = $this->getInfoInstance();

    var_dump($info->getAdditionalInformation());exit;
}
```

This always return :

```
array (size=1)
'method_title' => string 'Secure Pay' (length=10)
```

I tried everything, Im really lost on this problem, If someone can help me on this one that would be really helpfull

Thanks by advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the solution

just add in your model :

```
    /**
 * Set value after save payment from post data to use in case capture or authorize
 * @param \Magento\Framework\DataObject $data
 * @return $this
 */
public function assignData(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $data)
{
    parent::assignData($data);
    $this->getInfoInstance()->setAdditionalInformation('post_data_value', $data->getData());

    return $this;
}
```

Hope that can help someone !

Answer (score 0):

This is still valid for 2.3.5. I just extended a NAB transact extension to display and pass a reCaptcha token to the model. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Add the below function in your payment model file. Do not add key in setAdditionalInformation() otherwise, it will return old data instead of new data

app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Payment.php

```
 public function assignData(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $data)
        {
            parent::assignData($data);
            $this->getInfoInstance()->setAdditionalInformation($data->getData());
            return $this;
        }
```